# How to detect if a polygon has self-intersections?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Imagine you have a 2D polygon (a 2D [closed polygonal chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) to be more precise). How do you check if it contains self-intersections? It can be convex or concave, oriented clockwise or counter-clockwise.

Now, I could just run a standard `O(N log N)` algorithm to check if any two segments cross. But I believe that because we have some additional structure -- the order of the segments and the fact that each two consecutive segments meet at endpoints -- a simpler and faster (maybe `O(N)`?) algorithm could be devised.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Do you need just to check for self-intersections, or find all of them? The latter is harder than `O(N log N)`, as you can have `O(n^2)` intersections with `n` segments.

If you only need to find out if self-intersections exist, or find a small amount of them, then look [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.0893v2). This paper seems to claim just what you need, particularly in the polygon planarization section. I doubt implementing the algorithm described there would be simple, or worthwhile for any problem of reasonable size. But such an algorithm does exist. Disclaimer: I haven't tried to work through the paper and understand it.